# Angular JS dropdown.Selecting a value from a pop-up should update the value the value of dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a drop down in angular-JS which has list of entries.There is a button next to this drop-down that will open up one more pop-up and it has a table format.It has a list of radio boxes corresponding to each row.Each row has same value as that of drop down values.The challenge is when i select this radio button of one of the row,the drop down should get the updated value that is selected from the drop down.

HTML:

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-3" >
             <select id="bidowner" ng-model="bidowner" ng-options= "item.name for item in owners" required>
                <option ng-model = "bidOwner" value=''>Please Select</option>
            </select>

          <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light m-b-15" alt="default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#responsive-modal">
              <a href="#" class="text-white">Check Availability</a>
          </button>
   </div>
</div>




<div id="responsive-modal"   class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; z-index: 9999">
 <table class="table table-border">
     <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="x in list">
             <td align="center"><input name="sales" id="" value="1" required="" type="radio" ng-click="onSelected(x.name)"></td>
             <td>{{x.name}}</td>
             <td>{{x.n1}}</td>
          </tr> 
     </tbody> 
</table>
```

JS :

```
    var angularApp = angular.module("testApp", []);
    app.controller("testController",function($scope,$http){

          $scope.onSelected = function(value){
          $scope.bidOwner=value;
    }
 });
```

I tried doing this.But value in the drop down is not updating.

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var angularApp = angular.module("testApp", []);
app.controller("testController",function($scope,$http){
      $scope.onSelected = function(value){
             $scope.bidOwner=value;
             $scope.apply();  //add this line
      }
});


<div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-md-3" >
         <select id="bidOwner" ng-model="bidowner" ng-options= "item.name for item in owners" required>
         <option ng-model = "bidowner" value=''>Please Select</option>
 </select>
      <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light m-b-15" alt="default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#responsive-modal"><a href="#" class="text-white">Check Availability</a></button>
 </div>
 <div>




 <div id="responsive-modal"   class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; z-index: 9999">
 <table class="table table-border">
 <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in list">
                      <td align="center"><input name="sales" id="" value="1" required="" type="radio" ng-click="onSelected(x.name)"></td>
                      <td>{{x.name}}</td>
                      <td>{{x.n1}}</td>
       </tr> 
 </tbody>
```

Note: you are updating bidOwner but ngmodel name is bidowner which is case sentive

Comment: I tried that chamnging the model names.I made them same,Still not working

Comment: share in fiddle ,i will check